# Highcharter-R: x-axis values not showing up, wrong text on y-axis

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I am trying to create a mixed chart with highcharter R, see below the full code. I can't get rid of the following problems:

1. how to delete the text "Values" on both y-axes? I'd like only my text to show up ("xxx" and "yyy").
2. why are the x-axis values not showing up (2019, 2020a, 2020b) and instead below the columns "1", 2" and "3" appear? How could I change it?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
df2 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("Media", "Mediana"), each=3),
                  Anno=rep(c("2019", "2020a", "2020b"),2),
                  Reddito=c(40100, 39000, 38000, 34000, 33000, 32000))
df3<-data.frame(supp=rep(c("Numero indice media", "Numero indice mediana"), each=3),
                Anno=rep(c("2019", "2020a", "2020b"),2),
                Reddito=c(100, 97, 96, 100, 96, 95))

highchart() %>% 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(title = list(text = "xxx"),opposite=F),
         list(title = list(text = "yyy"),opposite=TRUE),
    list(lineWidth = 0),
    list(showLastLabel = F, opposite = T))%>% 
  hc_add_series(data = df2,type="column" ,hcaes(x = "Anno", y = 'Reddito', group = 'supp')) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = df3, type = "spline", hcaes(x = 'Anno', y = 'Reddito', group = 'supp'),yAxis = 1)
```

Comment: For part 2, I think highcharts does that for category type variables. Try making that a factor and then plotting it?

Comment: hi @Aman thank you for your answer, could you please provide an example?

Comment: Check the updated answer!

Comment: Although next time, it would be better to split your questions into two separate posts so that people can find it easier in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, try this:

```
library(highcharter)
highchart() %>% 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(title=list(text="xxx",margin = 20),
         lineWidth = 3,showLastLabel = FALSE,opposite = FALSE),
    list(
      title=list(text="yyy", margin = 20),
      lineWidth = 3,showLastLabel = FALSE,  opposite = T)
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = df2,type="column" ,hcaes(x = "Anno", y = 'Reddito', group = 'supp')) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = df3, type = "spline", hcaes(x = 'Anno', y = 'Reddito', group = 'supp'),yAxis = 1)
```

Values of xAxis aren't displayed in the way you expect, because you didn't define xAxis type, so they appear as index numbers by default. If you specify the type within `hc_xAxis` to `category`, it should work fine. Here's the final code:

```
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>% 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(title=list(text="xxx",margin = 20),
         lineWidth = 3,showLastLabel = FALSE,opposite = FALSE),
    list(
      title=list(text="yyy", margin = 20),
      lineWidth = 3,showLastLabel = FALSE,  opposite = T)
  ) %>% 
  # Specify Type
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = df2,type="column" ,hcaes(x = "Anno", y = 'Reddito', group = 'supp')) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = df3, type = "spline", hcaes(x = 'Anno', y = 'Reddito', group = 'supp'),yAxis = 1)
```